# How to call a cached xsl template from different class than init()

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, xslt, tomcat

Been researching xslts and found with JAXP cached xsl files in the `TransformerFactory.newTemplates(source)` is the way to go for a web application, transforming  a lot using the same xsl.

In most examples I have found code looks like this.

```
        Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
        TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Templates cachedXSLT = transFact.newTemplates(xsltSource);
        Transformer trans = cachedXSLT.newTransformer();
```

Calling the `newTransformer` in the same method.

What would be the best approach to let my  `init()` method on servlet cache them and create a new instance of `Transformer` with the cachedXSLT in different classes? How can I make reference to cachedXSLT outside of `init()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your `cachedXSLT` instance into [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). You need to register [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) in your web XML and the [contextInitialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method will be called by the container once. So if you add your instance to the `ServletContext` then it will be available across all the application.

To do that create a class which implements [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html):

```
public class YourContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {      
        //This method is called by the container on start up
        //Your code should look something like this:
       Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
       TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
       Templates cachedXSLT = transFact.newTemplates(xsltSource);
       Transformer trans = cachedXSLT.newTransformer();

       ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
       context.setAttribute("cashedXSLT", cachedXSLT);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {        
    }   

}
```

Register it in your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>your.package.YourContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In the [contextInitialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method you can get servlet context by using as below and add the attribute.

```
ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("cashedXSLT", cachedXSLT);
```

Then you can use:

```
Templates cashedXSLT = (Templates) context.getAttribute("cashedXSLT");
```

To get your `cachedXSLT` instance. To get [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) in your application depends on what framework you are using.

Comment: Thanks... The only difference I have is an existing `Initialization` servlet instead of `ServletContextListener`, but I have added this to the servlet that gets invoke on startup.

Answer (score 1):

Simply cache the `Templates` object against a key (e.g. full path to file name or whatever). Example with [guava's `LoadingCache`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained):

```
private final LoadingCache<String, Templates> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<String, Templates>() {
         public Graph load(String fileName) throws IOException {
             Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(fileName);
             TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
             return transFact.newTemplates(xsltSource); 
         }
       });

  ...then, somewhere in the method...

  Templates template = cache.get("/path/to/file.xslt");
```